# How is it possible to make the carousel work?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

Hope you're all fine. What I'm trying to do is to make this carousel working, I've checked the JS file which are at the end but still. I also respect the order of the js files. This is the example from the bootstrap website.

NB: test.css is empty

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="img/s1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/s2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Second slide label</h5>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/s3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h5>Third slide label</h5>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>


</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Cordially,

Comment: Refer to the Via JavaScript section in the bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: I do not understand your anwser...

Comment: please check this code. i just changes image path. it works good!. please be specific!!!
https://jsfiddle.net/Masud001/3tcgjLnp/2/

Comment: It does not work ! Should I need to clear something from my computer ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all `-bs-` eg. `data-bs-target` to `data-target` from your code and changes image path.

Comment: You are my savior. What is the use of the `bs` ? I've got another question if you allow me. My 3 pictures have different size, there is a way to make all 3 the same with some css ?